# CQ 5.6.1 On/Off Time in Page Properties doesn't work on Staging and Production

Tags: aem

I'm trying to use On Time and Off Time for activating the pages. But for some reason these functionalities doesn't work on Staging and Production environments.

Let me know root cause of this issue or how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you seeing any error in logs? Are pages published to publish instance after updating the on/off time on author instance? On/Off time work in different way as compared to Activate/Deactivate later.

Comment: I don't see anything miscellaneous in logs. The pages are not activated on publish instance after on/off time.
For now, we are using activate late and deactivate later but we want On/Off Time.

Answer (score 0):

On/Off time works in different way as compared to Activate/Deactivate later. From the [official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/page-authoring/editing-page-properties.html)

> **On Time** -
>   The date and time at which the published page will be activated. When
>   published this page will be kept dormant until the specified time.
>
> **Off Time**  -
>   The time at which the published page will be deactivated.

On/Off time would come into picture after the page is activated to publish instance. After the page is present on publish instance, on/off property is checked on publish instance to make page dormant or available.

Activate/Deactivate later would publish/deactivate the resource *from author to publish* after scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

To use on / off times, you need to do the following steps:

1. set on / off time(s).
2. Activate page manually. The content must be available on publish...
3. AEM/CQ will only deliver the page on request if ON_TIME <= CURRENT_TIME <= OFF_TIME.

Comment: I know how to use this functionality. But this is not happening on Staging and Production. Let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Can you list the steps you are doing and describe the exact error - there could be several reasons...Is a dispatcher involved?